# Allow users to use "Embed Code" or Script Editor webpart without full control

Tags: 2016, contribute, script-webpart

Is it possible to give users with **Contribute** permissions the possibility to **embed code** or insert a script editor webpart? All I can find online is about SharePoint Online but I am working on a **SharePoint 2016 on-premise environment**.

Answer (score -1):

If you edit the web part -

- Under webpart properties -->Advanced-->Target Audience
- You can provide permissions to the required users, so it wont be visible to others.

Done Enjoy!! :)

Comment: If I got that wrong this only hides the webpart for certain users. I have the problem that only users with full control can use embed code or script editor webpart.

Comment: Yes, that restriction will prevail off course.